# Date format (php&mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to have the german date format. In my table in phpmyadmin I have got the format type "DATE" and I am struggling in my query now.

```
$sql    =   "SELECT * 
         FROM workeroffers
         WHERE 0=0"
         .( $w_destrict ? " AND w_destrict LIKE '$w_destrict'":"" )
         .( $w_select ? " AND w_select LIKE '$w_select'":"" )
         .( $w_mjobs > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $w_mjobs," OR" )." )":"" )
         .( $w_mdestrict > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $w_mdestrict," OR" )." )":"" )
         ." ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( w_date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS w_date ASC;";
```

Something went wrong in this query and I am getting no result. Any idears?
Sorry, first time that I am doing it.

Here it is working, but in the wrong date format:

```
$sql    =   "SELECT * 
         FROM joboffers
         WHERE 0=0"
         .( $j_destrict ? " AND j_destrict LIKE '".$j_destrict."'":"" )
         .( $j_select ? " AND j_select LIKE '".$j_select."'":"" )
         .( $j_mjobs > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $j_mjobs," OR" )." )":"" )
         .( $j_mdestrict > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $j_mdestrict," OR" )." )":"" )
         ." ORDER BY j_date ASC;";
```

It is a diffrent table. Above it was just a try. I tought, it could go in the right direction.

Here is my code for the result:

```
<div class="table_padding">
<table class="responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>Jobart</th>
        <th>Stadteil</th>
        <th>Berufsfeld</th>
        <th class="table_titel">Title</th>
        <th>Vergütung</th>
        <th>Gesucht ab(Datum)</th>
        <th>Weitere Informationen</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

        foreach ( $inseration as $value ) { 

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?= $value['w_select'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $value['w_destrict'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $value['w_cat'] ?></td>
        <td class="table_titel"><?= $value['w_title'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $value['w_cash'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $value['w_date'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="index.php?site=Jobsuche_Inserat&w_id=

            <?php
                echo $value['w_id'];

                    if( $w_select ){
                        echo '&w_select=' . $value['w_select'];
                    }
                    if( $w_destrict ){ echo '&w_destrict=' . $value['w_destrict'];
                    }
                    if( $w_mjobs > "" ){ 
                    echo '&matches_job=' . implode(',', $_REQUEST['matches_job']); 
                    }
                    if( $w_mdestrict > "" ){ 
                    echo '&matches_destrict=' . implode( ',', $_REQUEST['matches_destrict'] ); 
                    }

            ?>

        ">Weiter</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php

        }

?>
</table>
```

Maby I tought wrong, I just want to have the output in the german date format!!

**Edit:**
OK cool, it is working with the correct date, but it is not ordered by date now. What did I wrong?

```
$sql    =   "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(w_date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS w_date, w_id, w_userid, w_select, w_cat, w_destrict, w_cash, w_title, w_desc, w_pic, w_email, w_phone, w_fax
         FROM workeroffers
         WHERE 0=0"
         .( $w_destrict ? " AND w_destrict LIKE '$w_destrict'":"" )
         .( $w_select ? " AND w_select LIKE '$w_select'":"" )
         .( $w_mjobs > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $w_mjobs," OR" )." )":"" )
         .( $w_mdestrict > "" ? " AND ( ".ltrim( $w_mdestrict," OR" )." )":"" )
         ." ORDER BY w_date ASC;";
```

Comment: `$w_mjobs > ""` huh. `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( w_date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS w_date ASC` heh..

Comment: Do you want the date format returned in the result, or do you want to order your result by the German date format?

Comment: both.. I would like to have the date in the result and ordered by date, but in german date format

Comment: Can you show your table definition and sample data on the table. I am not clear on why you are trying to order based on a date format.  If you have a date field you should just order based on that, you can change the format either in the select portion of your query or in the application.

Comment: Why the `0=0` in your query?  Why use `LIKE` without any wildcards (just use `=`)? I personally think you are trying to get too cute with the ternary operators here as well as it makes your query hard to read.

Comment: How can I change the output date format?

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( w_date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS w_date, [other fields] FROM ...`  You should get out of the bad habit of using `SELECT *` anyway, as it makes your code harder to read and potentially fragile if there is a DB schema change.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I got it now :D

Comment: So when you say it is not ordered by date now, do you mean you want an ordering such that 01.01.2014 would be ordered before 02.01.2013 in and ascending sort? In other words it is ordered by day, then by month, then by year?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your periods with dashes in your date format like so:

```
." ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( w_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS w_date ASC;";
```

Comment: it is not working. I am not sure, if I am using the "DATE_FORMAT" function correct.